# Kobold character for Kingmaker Pathfinder adventure

Tags: pathfinder-1e, adventure-path, kobold

I'm aiming for a high-charisma build to try to become the Kobold Queen.

The starting rules are:

Level 1, 200 GP, 15 point buy for being a standard fantasy setting, 2 traits.

I want to include the "Dragon Affinity" trait as I want to be a Kobold Bloodline Sorceror. The adventure path is intended to go from level 1 to at least 15 (15 is the level the final adventure in the path starts at).

Role-wise: be impressive and flashy while knowing a few sneaky trick spells, with the objective of inspiring misfits to come join our kingdom.

What is my best build plan for these objectives?

Comment: Hello Jasmine, welcome to RPG.SE. Take a look at the [tour] and (maybe) [help]. This site is not a forum, but a Q&A site, and as such, we don't allow questions asking for suggestions/recommendations in such a broad scope. I suggest you try to narrow the focus down. If you feel that is not possible (at this moment), I suggest you ask this question in a forum. We have compiled a list of good [fora here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: The site's happy (eager, even) to help optimize characters, but you've to provide a fairly detailed starting point. Because, although **kobold spymaster or treasurer for the *Kingmaker* adventure path** is pretty narrow, the site's [guidelines for character optimization questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1639/8610) demand a little more than that.

Comment: Helpful things you could expand on for your Kobold would be level, starting cash, abilities and roles you want them to be strong in and areas where you don't care.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clear and to make it look more like an optimization request.  Please review the edit.  If the edit introduced any errors, please edit the question again to correct them.  Also please include how high up in level you expect to go in this campaign.

Comment: Thank you for helping with the editing, KorvinStarmast! I've added the level range, sorry for getting this wrong on my first attempt! I appreciate all the help everyone's offered.

Comment: No need to apologise. The guidance and rules on what makes an acceptable question on this site can be a little daunting at first, and it can take a few goes until people get their heads around it. It doesn't help that optimisation questions are particularly tricky to get right :)

Comment: Just to clarify, this is for the pen-and-paper adventure path, and not the computer game based on it, right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had a very long night and managed to knock out the whole character sheet with help of an IRC channel and getting a bit obsessive over the items.

The end stats were:

STR 6 DEX 14 CON 6 INT 12 WIS 7 CHA 18

HP 4, AC 14, Init 2, FORT 4, REF 2, WILL 0

She's got a fancy pink scythe for coup de gracing since she focuses more on spells for damage - specifically she's got one of each type of elemental damage via her Kobold bloodline.

Electrical: Trap runes, 8 times per day thanks to the effective +2 to charisma for sorceror abilities
Fire: Spark (cantrip) and Grease (level 1)
Ice: Ray of Frost (cantrip)
Acid: Acid Splash (cantrip)

She's also got Message for her last cantrip and Mage Armour for her other level 1 spell; Stealth, Bluff and Craft (Trapmaking) are her skills she took ranks in partly due to racial buffs.

Her traits are Day Raider to remove her light sensitivity and Dragon Affinity for the effective +2 to charisma for sorceror abilities/spells.

Her feat is Kobold Confidence, which gives her charisma bonus to Fort saves and lets her survive up to her charisma in negatives before dying, keeping with the glass cannon idea I had for her.

She has a billow cape for pit traps, wears glasses and smoked goggles to fake being light sensitive (why not be underestimated?), has an armoured kilt, and dramatically flings away her cape and backpack when combat looms (which just barely gets her under her light load).

She's also so frail that she's afraid of water due to her swim penalty and as such bought a collapsible bath, along with a hanging tent and folding chair that are carried by a pack capybara (that sleeps in her tent with her cause she's a huge softie) due to her horrible strength score.

I'm also going with a backstory of her being raised by dwarves in a 'prodigal daughter returns' type deal (a la Captain Carrot Ironfoundersson), and she's got predominately white scales but has enough scales on her limbs that come from different draconic bloodlines, explaining why she's got enough kobold bloodline to gain the benefits of the Bloodline.

I think that's about everything, thank you all again for all the help, I greatly appreciate it!